# Populate dropdown from JSON I generated in php from database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have a dropdown and I'm trying to populate it in JQuery with informations from a JSON I generated in php.

PHP:

```
$return_arr = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table"; 

$result=mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conn'],$sql);


while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['field1'] = $row['field1'];
    $row_array['field2'] = $row['field2'];
    ...
    ...
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

JQuery:

```
$.post("php_file.php",{ajax: true},function(data, status){
            alert(data); // correct json
            $.each($.parseJSON(data), function(key,value){
                alert(value); // I get [Object object]
            });
        });
```

What I'm doing wrong here? Basically I'm trying to iterate the json from php (variable data) and populate my dropdown.

Comment: where are you populating dropdown?

Comment: Could you provide the json please?

Comment: Also try to use `console.debug("JSON", value)` instead of _alert_, in this way you won't see _[Object Object]_

Comment: Arpit Solanki, I am not populating the dropdown as of now, because I can't seem to iterate it.

Comment: How does your json data look like?

Comment: `{destination: "Destination", source: "Source", landing: "16:30:00", takeoff: "10:30:00"}`

I want my droplist to have the values separated by comma for each entry array

For example in this case the first and only line would be `Destination, Source, 16:30:00,  10:30:00`

Comment: Check that for this code `var data = { destination: "Destination", source: "Source", landing: "16:30:00", takeoff: "10:30:00" };
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            alert(value); // I get [Object object]
        });`, you would not get [Object object] as you seem to claim.

Comment: Tell us what is there in `value` so that `alert(value);` says `[Object object]`.

Comment: Actually, if I do `console.log(value)` I get the expected output. But if I try to do something like `$("#myDropDown").append("<option>" + value + "</option">);` I still get `[Object object]` .

Comment: @Hansewl Can you console.log(value) and show what's in there?